# Beamerposter missing header with title

Tags: beamer, header-footer, beamerposter

I am struggling to create a poster presentation with `beamerposter`. 
What I am simply trying to do is to reproduce the examples in the github page; one of which is this [one](https://github.com/deselaers/latex-beamerposter/blob/master/examples/00/example.tex):

```
  \documentclass[final]{beamer} % beamer 3.10: do NOT use option hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false} !
  %\documentclass[final,hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer} % beamer 3.07: get rid of beamer warnings
  \mode<presentation> {  %% check http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php for examples
    \usetheme{Berlin}    %% you should define your own theme e.g. for big headlines using your own logos 
  }
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
  %\usepackage{times}\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  % times is obsolete
  \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
  \boldmath
  \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}                       % e.g. for DIN-A0 poster
  %\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a1,scale=1.4,grid,debug]{beamerposter}                  % e.g. for DIN-A1 poster, with optional grid and debug output
  %\usepackage[size=custom,width=200,height=120,scale=2,debug]{beamerposter}                     % e.g. for custom size poster
  %\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.0,printer=rwth-glossy-uv.df]{beamerposter}   % e.g. for DIN-A0 poster with rwth-glossy-uv printer check
  % ...
  %
  \title[Fancy Posters]{Making Really Fancy Posters with \LaTeX}
  \author[Dreuw \& Deselaers]{Philippe Dreuw and Thomas Deselaers}
  \institute[RWTH Aachen University]{Human Language Technology and Pattern Recognition,RWTH Aachen University}
  \date{Jul. 31th, 2007}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{} 
  \vfill
  \begin{block}{\large Fontsizes}
  \centering
  {\tiny tiny}\par
  {\scriptsize scriptsize}\par
  {\footnotesize footnotesize}\par
  {\normalsize normalsize}\par
  {\large large}\par
  {\Large Large}\par
  {\LARGE LARGE}\par
  {\veryHuge veryHuge}\par
  {\VeryHuge VeryHuge}\par
  {\VERYHuge VERYHuge}\par
\end{block}
    \vfill
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Across all the examples that I saw, there is no need to do a classical `\maketitle`, it shall be incorporated into the beamer template how to render the title in the headline. However I am not able to see any headline title!

This is what I get after compiling with `pdflatex`:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard [`beamer`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) themes are set up for presentations rather than posters and so it shouldn't be a surprise that they look inappropriate. The `headline` is in fact functioning correctly - add `\section{Foo}\subsection{Bar}` before the frame and you can see this appear in the section title but in normal-sized text which looks tiny on a poster.

[image]

Indeed this is even mentioned in a comment on the code you've given `%% you should define your own theme e.g. for big headlines using your own logos`

You might like to take a look at (or use directly) some of the themes the developer provides for beamerposter to get an idea of what is needed to customise a standard theme https://github.com/deselaers/latex-beamerposter

The below is a simple redefinition of `headline` to work with the `Berlin` theme in a manner suitable for [`beamerposter`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamerposter) something similar may be necessary for the `footline`, alternatively you can use one of the themes from https://github.com/deselaers/latex-beamerposter as a more readily hackable solution

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Berlin}
}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}
\title[Fancy Posters]{Making Really Fancy Posters with \LaTeX}
\author[Dreuw \& Deselaers]{Philippe Dreuw and Thomas Deselaers}
\institute[RWTH Aachen University]{Human Language Technology and Pattern Recognition,RWTH Aachen University}
\date{Jul. 31th, 2007}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt,wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}
        \centering
        \vskip2ex
        \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\LARGE{\strut\inserttitle}}}
        \vskip2ex
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt,wd=\paperwidth]{middle separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{subsection in head/foot}
        \centering
        \vskip2ex
        \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\large{\strut\insertauthor}}}
        \vskip2ex
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt,wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{} 
\vfill
\begin{block}{\large Fontsizes}
\centering
{\tiny tiny}\par
{\scriptsize scriptsize}\par
{\footnotesize footnotesize}\par
{\normalsize normalsize}\par
{\large large}\par
{\Large Large}\par
{\LARGE LARGE}\par
{\veryHuge veryHuge}\par
{\VeryHuge VeryHuge}\par
{\VERYHuge VERYHuge}\par
\end{block}
\vfill
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]